# Extend Flex Spark Button to contain a clickable Checkbox

Tags: apache-flex, button, actionscript, skin, flex-spark

I'm using a Sparkskin for a Button to put a checkbox on the button.

Currently the button is receiving the mouse click and the checkbox is not selectable.

I want a user to be able to select/deselect the checkbox.

Do I need to set something or override a function in the Sparkskin for that to happen?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

First, create your custom button extending spark Button. Set `mouseChildren` property to `true` (after `super()` call). Override `mouseEventHandler` method, which handles all mouse events of the button. Check for the `target` of event and don't call for `super.mouseEventHandler` if `target` is your checkbox in case you don't want your button to be clicked when checking the checkbox.

```
 public class MyButton extends Button {
        [SkinPart]
        public var checkBox:CheckBox;

        public function MyButton() {
            super();
            mouseChildren = true;
        }

        override protected function mouseEventHandler(event:Event):void {
            if (event.target != checkBox)
                super.mouseEventHandler(event);
            }
        }
 }
```